# Is one bound in open D6 in any way to the list of skills and where to put them?

Tags: ogl, d6-system

With open D6 (all applications of it) you get different skill lists and under which attribute to put them. Most publications that use open D6 seem to almost completely use only skills from this lists under the same attributes.

So my question is: If I want to create/publish something under open D6 am I in anyway bound to the skill names, descriptions (aka the skills themselves) and where to put them (under which attribute) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The Open Gaming License that Open D6 uses does not prohibit making your own game design decisions when borrowing from Open D6's text. You can bend, fold, spindle, and mutilate the borrowed text as much or as little as you like, so long as you obey the license requirements.

Skill lists are simply drudgery to design. Having a ready-made list means you can avoid that dull work and get on to the fun parts of designing a game. That is the simplest likely explanation for why existing uses of Open D6 haven't bothered changing this. It's definitely not because they weren't allowed.